# Filter nvarchar column by whether the value can be cast as a date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table, whose ETL process and contents that I cannot change, with an `nvarchar` column that mostly consists of date strings and null. However, there are the occasional 'N/A' or 'Not accepted' sprinkled in.

Is there a way I can get only the values that are valid date strings?

INPUT:

```
2019-01-01
N/A
null
2019-03-04
```

OUTPUT

```
2019-01-01
2019-03-04
```

Comment: TRY_PARSE? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Note that this is not using an index - not sargeable. BAD performance. Try_parse in a function on a field that then is indexed would work.

Comment: Let's not beat around the bush though fixing the data itself (changing it to a `date`) is the real solution here. The examples you give both have the format `yyyy-MM-dd` but I would not be surprised you have values like `01/02/03`, and you are in for a world of hurt if so.

Comment: @Larnu I agree, but it is a third-party database and they already told me they won't fix it.

Comment: "Won't" doesn't mean shouldn't or can't. I would personally be pushing for the the third party to fix it; it's not a "feature" it's a bug and would be raising a support call in regards to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way uses `try_cast()` or `try_convert()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where try_cast(datecol as date) is not null;
```